# React Native fetch: Undefined is not an object

Tags: react-native, fetch

trying to use fetch in react native and getting

```
Unable to symbolicate stack trace: Requiring module "node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\fetch.js", which threw an exception: TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.

Unable to symbolicate stack trace: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[5], "../../Network/fetch").fetch')
```

Here's my code

This is the first screen of the app

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
    state = {
        loginURL:''
    };

    componentDidMount(): void {
        fetch('http://10.0.2.2:4607/imgur/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => {
                if(json.type === 'redirect') this.setState({'loginURL': json.data});
            });
    };

    render(){
        return (<View><Text>Hello</Text></View>);
    };
}
```

I've tried removing the node_modules directory and re-running `npm install` but same issue. Happening on the simulator

My package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.2.3",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.3.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.3",
    "appcenter": "3.0.0",
    "appcenter-analytics": "3.0.0",
    "appcenter-crashes": "3.0.0",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-render-html": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^11.0.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^8.2.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.3.3"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when i enabled debugger mode, I received a further error

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'forEach' of object '#<Headers>'
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined

Error: Requiring module "node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\fetch.js", which threw an exception: TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'forEach' of object '#<Headers>'
```

On a module, I've included a forEach polyfill to loop through and object like you would an array. EG:

```
if (!Object.prototype.forEach) {
    Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'forEach', {
        value: function (callback, thisArg) {
            if (this == null) throw new TypeError('Not an object');

            for (let key in this) {
                if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) callback.call(thisArg, this[key], key, this);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

When i remove this code, everything works as expected! I can't find the code responsible for throwing the exception but at-least I know the cause is my own code :)

Answer (score -1):

This may be unrelated, but why are you using quotation marks on your setState?
Should not this:

```
this.setState({'loginURL': json.data});
```

be like this:

```
this.setState({loginURL: json.data});
```

Comment: Thank you, Javascript supports both so it doesn't really make a difference.

Comment: This is not an answer, please use comment feature in the future.